# My wireless connection went down suddenly, and I cannot get it back

Tags: networking

The other night the wireless connection suddenly quit working on my laptop running Ubuntu.  I looked at the network settings, and nothing looked different or wrong.  I rebooted the machine a couple times, still nothing.  I tried a direct ethernet wired connection, and it is fine (i'm using it now to ask this question and provide a link to my pasted wireless connection).  All the other wireless devices in the house are fine.  Here is the link to the wireless info text file in the ubuntu pastebin as requested:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/14675462/

Please, any help would be appreciated.  i'm not much of a Linux guy, so I'm looking to the experts here.  Thanks so much.

Comment: What laptop model do you have?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

Ok, well I feel stupid.  Not being very familiar with the Network Menu, I did not notice that the option indicating the status of the Wireless Hardware Switch was OFF.  I discovered thru 5 min of research that there is a wireless antenna switch on my keyboard, and where it was.  It is located in a row of other switches at the top of my keyboard beside the lighted ON/OFF power switch, and is iconized by a "broadcasting antenna" picture.  My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite A665.  I must have accidentally pressed it to turn it off the other night.  Sorry for the silly problem, but there are so many similar forum posts, I figured I had a real problem.  Maybe this is actually the problem others are having.